# signlar concurrent connections with iis 8 on Win Server Essentials 2012

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I had a signlar app that ran on my windows 10 pro box. I used IIS on it and it allowed me to have 10 concurrent connections.

But now I needed to expand my concurrent connections to my app. So I purchased some new hardware and Windows Server Essentials 2012.

I just setup my signlar app and started opening up browser windows to test it on the new box and I couldn't get more than 4 connections open at once. The fifth browser page just hangs. as soon as I close another browser page the hanging page appears.

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: You seem to be hitting browser connection limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: @Pawel that's a bingo! thanks so much. It's weird chrome win 10 pro allowed more which threw me for a loop.